# What is a time-planning application that allows me to record if time was spent in the planned way or not?

Tags: time-management

I do a lot of personal self-studying (learning Swedish) and have a fixed gym schedule, etc. What would really help me in terms of motivation is if I had some kind of calendar/time-planning app that would a) allow me to schedule repeatable events and b) allow me to record if I completed it or not.

So, if I scheduled 6PM on Thursday for 1 hour of study time, afterwards I should be able to check a box to say I actually did it. Ability to view stats, history, etc would be a bonus.

Anyone know of anything like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you have a Google account, you can set up calendars with recurring tasks that allow you to check things off as you do them.

There are also more minimal straight to do lists like TuexDuex which automatically moves unfinished tasks to the next day or something like Remember the Milk.

Then there are the old standbys using Microsoft Office with pop up that you can dismiss as you do them or Thunderbird on the open source side.

If you're managing time down to the minute I'd suggest some sort of Gantt software that blocks out segments of time.